# Search for old answers

Tags: feature-request, search

Is there any simple method to search for my old answers , I have more answers , but I can' reach quickly to a specific question ?

Is it applicable to add a Search TextBox in answers tab as Search TextBox Users Page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But, of course! Search is one of the most powerful tools we have here. To get your posts, you simply type `user:me`, and you'll get all your posts!

*Nice, but how do I get only my answers, and not my questions?*

Equally simple, just add the is:answer to user:me, and you'll have your answers. `user:me is:answer`.

*Oh! I'm starting to like this. But I have several hundreds of answers, and what I'm looking for is just answers containing User Profile. How does this work?*

Well, just continue to concatenate your string and add "User Profile", to your search: `user:me is:answer "User Profile"`.

Try this out yourself [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+%22User+Profile%22).

All of this and more magic can be found in our help center, specifically in the article [How do I search?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Wow , that what I need . many thanks, Mr. @Benny